# google actions: conversation content order with rich response

Tags: actions-on-google

I am able to use the `SimpleResponse`, `BasicCard`, `List` and other such rich responses. Can the following be supported?

a. **only speech + basicCard + simpleResponse**

if I build a response such as:

```
conv.ask('<speak> ...</speak>');
conv.ask(new BasicCard(
 );
conv.ask(new SimpleResponse({
   speech: ...
   text: ...
});
```

I notice that on display devices (phone), the content of the `speak` appears as text too. Is there a way to avoid it?

Next, the text of the Simple Response appears before the Card. Is there a way to ensure it appears after the card.

Currently, for the first problem, I am forced to use a SimpleResponse with a short text (like Hi) and for the second problem, I have put the text as the card text and remove the SimpleResponse.

But would like to know if there is a way out? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all; As stated in the [reference docs for the node.js library](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/conversation_response.richresponse.html#items), the first item in your response should always be a SimpleResponse. And a SimpleResponse always shows a text, whether it's a short text that you define or the transcription of its `speech` property. But I like that you're putting a short text instead to avoid showing the user what your Action says verbatim.

Second; from my experience, the order of the responses aren't shown accurately on the simulator. I've tested your case in a dummy Action and while the simulator shows the Final Response (which is last in my code) before the card, my phone shows them in the correct order.

**Simulator:**

[image: Simulator Screenshot]

**Smartphone:**
[image: Smartphone Screenshot]

Test in on a device and see if the error persists. I currently don't have my Google Home near me but test on it as well if you can.

Comment: Thanks @Yuksel Tolun. Let me confirm what you shared and will mark the answer.

Comment: That worked perfectly @Vuksel Tolun. Thanks. I realised that at times the Basic Card contents too are not showing on the simulator. Have switched to checking the code on a mobile phone.

Comment: Glad I could help ^^

Answer (score 0):

For your first problem: If you want to use ssml tags you are forced to use a SimpleResponse, that's how it's meant to be. In other words your first problem is not a problem :)

Comment: Thanks @ANton Eriksson. But even in a Simple Response there is some text the **needs** to be displayed and in the absense of providing it takes the ssml content. That is why I replaced it with a simple "Hi". Just wanted to confirm if I can **avoid** the text totally. Apparently does not seem so.